# How to add custom condition in Action tab in Shopping cart price rule

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

I want to add some custom condition in magento shopping cart price rule action tab as shown in figure :

[image]

How to add custom `date type` condition here and apply on cart it on frontend?